# Problemas no projeto - Firebase + Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics-api

Olá.

Uso o Google Newsstand Producer gerando artigos do meu site para o Google News App. Para usar o Analytics, foi necessária a criação de um projeto no Firebase.

Já criei, e quando voltei ao Analytics, ele encontrou esse projeto e conectou. Mas lá no Analytics não aparece o código ID de acompanhamento (ex UA-000000000-1) que preciso para colocar no Google Newsstand Producer.

Preciso fazer mais alguma coisa no Firebase pra esse código aparecer? tenho que fazer o authentication, database, etc?

PS. Não estou tentando criar um aplicativo, apenas (como solicitado na documentação do Google) criei o tal projeto no Firebase.

Obrigado